# Filtering Object into two groups by matched object key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say that I have the following object

```
var transformers = [
  {
    name: 'Optimus Prime',
    form: 'Freightliner Truck',
    team: 'Autobot'
  },
  {
    name: 'Megatron',
    form: 'Gun',
    team: 'Decepticon'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bumblebee',
    form: 'VW Beetle',
    team: 'Autobot'
  },
  {
    name: 'Soundwave',
    form: 'Walkman',
    team: 'Decepticon'
  }
];
```

How can I render two groups depending on the `team` value

```
<div>
<h1>Autobot Team</h1>
... //Here goes the corresponding matches
</div>
<div>
<h1>Decepticon Team</h1>
... //Here goes the corresponding matches
</div>
```

I tried this with no luck

```
renderTeam(){
  transformers.map(team =>{
   if(team.team === "Autobot"){
    return(
     <div>{team.name}</div>
    )
   }
   if(team.team === "Decepticon"){
    return(
     <div>{team.name}</div>
    )
   }
  })
}
<div>
 <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
  {this.renderTeam()}
</div>
<div>
 <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
  {this.renderTeam()}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `renderTeam` could take a string parameter that allows you to filter and map the array:

```
renderTeam(team) {
  return transformers
    .filter(transformer => transformer.team === team)
    .map(transformer => (<div key={transformer.name}>{transformer.name}</div>);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="transformer-teams">
      <div>
        <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
        {renderTeam('Autobot')}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Decepticon Team</h1>
        {renderTeam('Decepticon')}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that pass a parameter to `renderTeam` method that will contain any one team name, and it will return the ui elements. Don't forgot to return the result from that `renderTeam` method.

Also assign **unique key** to each element inside loop.

Like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
    {this.renderTeam('Autobot')}
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
    {this.renderTeam('Decepticon')}
</div>

renderTeam(team){
    let items = [];
    transformers.forEach((item,i) => {
        if(item.team === team)
            items.push(<div key={i}>{item.name}</div>);         
    })
    return items;
}
```

But with this approach you need to run the same loop again, so to avoid that you can write it like this also:

```
renderTeam(){
    let team1 = [], team2 = [];
    transformers.forEach((item,i) => {
        if(item.team === 'Autobot')
            team1.push(<div key={i}>{item.name}</div>);
        else if(item.team === 'Decepticon')
            team2.push(<div key={i}>{item.name}</div>);
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
                {team1}
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>Autobot Team</h1>
                {team2}
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.renderTeam()}
        </div>
    )
}
```